# How to filter by language in default search

Tags: 7, search

On a D7 (7.60) site, we're currently using the default search tool for a little search form block on the page. Our site has multiple language versions, dependent on url.

Right now, content in 4 languages is giving 4 search results. I want to filter this to just current user's language. But when I go into the view (admin/structure/views/view/search/edit), I'm not seeing "current user's language" as a filter.

Answer (score 2):

Ah heck.. nevermind. I wasn't understanding how to get that setting. All good now. Filter by content language, and 'current user's language' is one of the checkbox options within it.
[image]

Comment: Could you maybe add a screenshot or something else to make this answer even more relevant to future readers?